# Azure Function query collection from CosmosDB using Javascript

Tags: javascript, azure, timer, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

**Background**

I tried to read the documents from my collection from CosmosDB which stored in my collection within the last hour.

**How I did that:**

to do that I followed these steps:

1. create new azure function with timer (0 0 * * * *)
2. in Input section I created the connection with my collect
3. tried to read the documents from the collection, but I got always an error.

**This is the code that i tried:**

```
module.exports = function (context, myTimer) {
    var timeStamp = new Date().toISOString();
    if(myTimer.isPastDue)
    {
        context.log('JavaScript is running late!');
    }
    context.log('JavaScript timer trigger function ran!:', timeStamp);   
    var documents = context.bindings.documents;
    for (var i = 0; i < documents.length; i++) {
        var document = documents[i];
        context.log('First document modified : ', document);
    }       
    context.done();
};
```

**Error that i got:**

Exception while executing function: Functions.CosTriggerJs. Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client: Message: {"errors":[{"severity":"Error","location":{"start":19,"end":20},"code":"581010","message":"Syntax error, invalid token ';'."}]}

**My question is:**

Because I could not find any documentation on the internet about this problem, Can anyone provide me a documentation or answer me how I can write a function using the timer and read a CosmosDB collection.

Comment: can you please add code to show what exactly you tried?

Comment: i edit my post now. please take a look on the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for the error.

i made a mistake when i added the CosmosDB as input in Azure Portal

the mistakes is:
in SQL Query Field i added a (;) at the end of the SQL statement.
removing this (;) make every thing work well.